# Spring OpenAPI-generator forces @RequestParts and Unsupported Media Type

Tags: spring, openapi, openapi-generator-maven-plugin

i am trying to implements an simple Spring FileUpload with OpenApi support.
I am using spring-boot:2.5.8 and openapi-generator-maven-plugin:5.3.1

Here is my OAS:

```
  /api/datas/{id}:
post:
  operationId: uploadFile
  tags:
    - file
  parameters:
    - in: path
      name: id
      required: true
      schema:
        type: integer
  requestBody:
    content:
      multipart/form-data:
        schema:
          type: object
          required:
            - file
            - docName
          properties:
            file:
              type: string
              format: binary
            docName:
              type: string
            docGroup:
              type: integer
```

The OpenApi Generator creates such a method.

```
    @RequestMapping(
    method = RequestMethod.POST,
    value = "/api/datas/{id}",
    consumes = { "multipart/form-data" }
)
default ResponseEntity<Void> uploadFile(
      @ApiParam(value = "", required = true) @PathVariable("id") Integer id,
      @ApiParam(value = "")           @Valid @RequestPart(value = "file", required = true) MultipartFile file,
      @ApiParam(value = "", required = true) @Valid @RequestPart(value = "docName", required = true) String docName,
      @ApiParam(value = "") @Valid @RequestPart(value = "docGroup", required = false) Integer docGroup) {
    return new ResponseEntity<>(HttpStatus.NOT_IMPLEMENTED);

}
```

The problem is that Spring does not have a HttpMessageConverter for types like Integer, Enum or Date an so on which i want be able to define as requestBody, so Spring throws a 'Unsupported Media Type' Exception.

Do i really need to implement a bunch of MessageConverters for simple Types, or is there a better solution?
I tried to force the spring-openapi-generator to create @RequestParam for simple properties, but no idea how.

At the end i want to be able to POST a simple Form with a File in it, and i need to use OpenApi for that.